# Referencing child component from styled component

Tags: html, css, reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I'm trying to create a hoverable help icon but can't seem to be able to control the state of the help box from the hover event of the help icon.

A full working example of the issue can be found here https://codesandbox.io/s/info-drop-down-th88d?file=/src/HelpIcon.tsx

According to the styled-components [docs](https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced#caveat) I need to wrap my react components in `styled()`:

```
const StyledInfoIcon = styled(InfoIcon)``;
const StyledInfoBox = styled(InfoBox)``;
```

This does allow me to control the behavior of the child components, for example:

```
const HelpWrapper = styled.div`
  ${StyledInfoIcon}:hover {
    display: none;
  }
`;
```

Works as expected, when I hover on the icon, it disappears, but unfortunately adding the extra selector for the text box:

```
const HelpWrapper = styled.div`
  ${StyledInfoIcon}:hover ${StyledInfoBox} {
    display: none;
  }
`;
```

Doesn't.

Any help is appreciated, I'm wondering if there is a better way to go about this problem in general that I'm not aware of. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Brief

The components are adjacent, so you won't be to control the visibility of one with the other using CSS selectors; also, you won't be able to maintain the same hover trigger height/width. Instead, I'd recommend using React state with `onMouseEnter` and `onMouseLeave` event listeners.

### Problem

While you can leverage the `HelperWrapper` and styled selectors, you'll run into CSS issues:

```
import styled from "styled-components";

import InfoIcon from "./InfoIcon";
import InfoBox from "./InfoBox";

const StyledInfoIcon = styled(InfoIcon)``;
// initially set tooltip to not be displayed
const StyledInfoBox = styled(InfoBox)`display: none;`;

// when the HelpWrapper is hovered, change the StyledInfoBox display to a block
const HelpWrapper = styled.div`
  :hover > ${StyledInfoBox} {
    display: block;
  }
`;

const HelpIcon = () => {
  return (
    <HelpWrapper>
      <StyledInfoIcon />
      <StyledInfoBox text="We are having waffles for breakfast" />
    </HelpWrapper>
  );
};

export default HelpIcon;
```

Since the `HelpWrapper` wraps both components, it'll adjust its height/width to encompass **both** components:

Before hovering:
[image]

After hovering:
[image]

which is not really achieving the desired effect of only hovering over the info icon to display a tooltip.

### Solution

In this case, I'd recommend using React state with mouse event listeners instead.

#### Demo

[image: Edit Info Drop Down (forked)]

#### Code

**HelpIcon.tsx**

```
import * as React from "react";
import InfoIcon from "./InfoIcon";
import InfoBox from "./InfoBox";

const HelpIcon = (): React.ReactElement => {
  const [showTooltip, setTooltipVisiblity] = React.useState(false);

  const handleOnEnter = (): void => {
    setTooltipVisiblity(true);
  };

  const handleOnLeave = (): void => {
    setTooltipVisiblity(false);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <InfoIcon onMouseEnter={handleOnEnter} onMouseLeave={handleOnLeave} />
      <InfoBox
        showTooltip={showTooltip}
        text="We are having waffles for breakfast"
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default HelpIcon;
```

**InfoBox.tsx**

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import type { ReactElement } from "react";

type InfoBoxProps = {
  className?: string;
  text: string;
  maxWidth?: string;
  showTooltip?: boolean;
};

const InfoBoxComponent = (props: InfoBoxProps): ReactElement => (
  <div className={props.className}>
    <div className="arrow" />
    <p>{props.text}</p>
  </div>
);

const InfoBox = styled(InfoBoxComponent)<InfoBoxProps>`
  position: relative;
  display: ${(props) => (props.showTooltip ? "block" : "none")};

  width: fit-content;
  max-width: ${(props) => (props.maxWidth ? props.maxWidth : "200px")};

  white-space: normal;

  background-color: #475f6a;
  color: white;

  box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px #00000029;
  border-radius: 5px;

  font-family: "Arial";
  font-size: 0.875rem;

  p {
    padding: 1rem;
  }

  .arrow {
    position: absolute;
    right: 15%;
    top: -16px;

    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 9px solid transparent;
    border-right: 9px solid transparent;

    border-bottom: 16px solid #475f6a;
  }
`;

export default InfoBox;
```

**InfoIcon.tsx**

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import type { ReactElement } from "react";

type InfoIconProps = {
  className?: string;
  onMouseEnter: () => void;
  onMouseLeave: () => void;
};

const InfoIconComponent = (props: InfoIconProps): ReactElement => (
  <svg
    className={props.className}
    onMouseEnter={props.onMouseEnter}
    onMouseLeave={props.onMouseLeave}
    viewBox="0 0 100 100"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  >
    <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="50%" />
    <text x="50%" y="50%" dominantBaseline="central" textAnchor="middle">
      i
    </text>
  </svg>
);

const InfoIcon = styled(InfoIconComponent)`
  height: 20px;
  user-select: none;

  circle {
    fill: #83add0;

    :hover {
      fill: #475f6a;
    }
  }

  text {
    fill: white;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 4rem;
    font-weight: 700;
  }
`;

export default InfoIcon;
```

**index.tsx**

```
import * as React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import HelpIcon from "./HelpIcon";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <HelpIcon />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Comment: This is great! thanks for taking the time to write such a thorough answer, I learned a lot! I noticed that you write your React components, then the styled-components after, I've not seen that before, is this recommended practice or personal preference? Thanks

Comment: Makes it easier for composition. For example, if you wanted to use composed styled selectors (like your `HelperWrapper` example), then all you'll need to do is import the component!

Comment: Ahh yes! Makes total sense, thank you again :)